# SIgnalR: How to send exceptions to client on connect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

In the hub i want to authenticate the clients based on Connection Header.
If the client is not allowed to connect, i want to throw an Exception with the detailed error.
But, if i throw an exception on the hub, the client only receives "(500) Internal Server Error"

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    string clientKey = Context.Headers["clientKey"];
    string version = Context.Headers["version"];
    if (!this.isValid(clientKey, version))
        throw new InvalidOperationException("SIGNALR: Invalid client");

    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

What i have to do to send the exception properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of throwing exception, you can simply call a client side JAVASCRIPT function with proper error message.

Comment: @MokshShah The clients are C# console applications, not javascript

Comment: It doesn't matter what your client is. Just understand the basics of what we are saying. Do not return an exception from your server. Return a message saying "You can't connect" and then let your client realize that it is an error condition. What your client is, and how it handles that is entirely up to you.

Comment: Im not much aware about console app based client, but main idea is, do not throw exception from server, you may log into database or as per your architecture design, but from here, simply call some function of client with proper message.Exactly as @BillGregg has commented

Comment: @BillGregg Thanks for the reply. After read your reply i will review my approach to this problem.

Comment: @MokshShah I will do that. In this case, i need to investigate how to return the message to SignalR client in OnConnected method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When error is going to happen you can return that error or return your custom message to the client and based of that message you can redirect the client to Error page or display dialog that indicates that Error has happened.

Don't throw the error on the server side. Return the error on the client side and notify the user

Comment: How can i do it in signalR method OnConnected? My issue here is that i can't return the error in this method.

Comment: try using $.connection.hub.error to catch errors on the client

Comment: The clients are C# console applications, not javascript.

Comment: try using Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).errorMessage("SIGNALR: Invalid client"); in OnConnected method where errorMessage is a method that you call from the client

Comment: I know that will work. But i want to do this without calling a client's method (only return the exception). If isn't possible, i will have to follow that approach.

Answer (score 1):

To enable sending error details to clients you should enable this in your Hub configuration. add this line of code in your startup class.

```
var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration {EnableDetailedErrors = true};
app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
```

Comment: Great! I will supplement the answer for core 3.1 -> in startUp add: services.AddSignalR(options =>options.EnableDetailedErrors = true);